# Convergence of expectations of product of r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value

I am trying to prove (or disprove) this proposition:

Let $(X_{n})_{n \ge 0}$ and $(Y_{n})_{n \ge 0}$ be two sequences of random variables, defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Assume that:

1-. $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are non-negative sequences  bounded above by $1$.

2-. $(X_{n})_{n \ge 0}$ converges a.s. to a constant $c > 0$.

3-. $\lim_{n \to \infty }\mathbb{E}(Y_{n})=d$.

Under the above conditions: is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}(X_{n}Y_{n})=cd$?

Observe that if $d=0$, we would have:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X_{n}Y_{n})\le \mathbb{E}(Y_{n})
\end{align}

because $X_{n}$ is bounded above; and so, in this case the result is easy.

But, what happens when $d >0$? Does the proposition hold in the general case? And, if not, can anyone provide a counter-example?

Comment: How about utilizing the inequality? \begin{align*}
\left| \mathbb{E}[X_nY_n] - cd \right|
&= \left| \mathbb{E}[(X_n-c)Y_n] + c(\mathbb{E}[Y_n]-d) \right| \\
&\leq  \|Y_n\|_{\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ \left| X_n - c \right| \right] + \lvert c \rvert \cdot\lvert \mathbb{E}[Y_n] - d \rvert
\end{align*}

Comment: It seems right to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need independence of $X_n$ and $Y_n$.  Otherwise first equality in proof may not hold.

Comment: I think that independence is not needed. The R.H.S at the equality of the first line above is just a rearrangement of the L.H.S. The inequality of the second line follows from triangle inequality and, then, from the fact that $Y_{n}$ is bounded.